# git log -n 1 --format="%ct" branchname is not working as expected, anyhing i am missing

Tags: linux, git

Tring to run command
git log -n 1 --format="%ct" **branchname** is not working as expected for other branches except for master as below, anything am i missing here, need help

```
$ git ls-remote --heads origin
9c4f1a56f01215e15065fc11a8882bfb44654458        refs/heads/license-details(s)-devenv,combine
9c4f1a56f01297e15065fc11a8882bfb44654458        refs/heads/updated/license-details-env,noncombine
6543d07ed9ub0e27f1d5f9234cd0f0188439bef8        refs/heads/Validat
ef7ef4a941e93dac3310e5951c0d7394ae14153a        refs/heads/dev
9c4f1a56f01217e85065fc11a8882bfb44654458        refs/heads/license-details(s)--devenv,combined
eecabff3ccba3719c3b203a2c5992c009541958a        refs/heads/master

trying to find the committer date in UNIX timestamp

$ git log -n 1 --format="%ct" refs/heads/master
1631819811


$ git log -n 1 --format="%ct" refs/heads/updated/license-details(s)-devenv,combine

fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/heads/updated/license-details(s)-devenv,combine': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ git log -n 1 --format="%ct" refs/heads/license-details-env,noncombine

fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/heads/license-details-env,noncombine': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - why are double dashes needed when running a command on a deleted file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973182/git-why-are-double-dashes-needed-when-running-a-command-on-a-deleted-file)

Comment: Are you running the `git log` command on the remote machine that hosts `origin`? If not, did you `git fetch` before?

Comment: run `git branch -a` on your local machine, to see what branches you can actually name

Answer (score 0):

git ls-remote --heads origin; List references in a remote repository.
Need git pull/fetch, to get the remote refs to local.
Then could find such refs by locally.